# sass how to instantiate an empty variable to be set by @if

Tags: css, variables, if-statement, sass, instantiation

I think the code speaks for itself so this is what I have:

```
@mixin btnNoBackgr30($divName, $iconName, $xtypeYesOrNo ){
$xtypeBtn:nil;
@if xtypeYesOrNo == 'yes'{
     $xtypeBtn:x-button-#{$divName};
  }
@if xtypeYesOrNo == 'no'{
   $xtypeBtn:#{$divName};
}

.#{$xtypeBtn}{
    properties:values;
}
```

all I get in css is this

```
.nil{
    properties:values;
}
```

How can instantiate the variable outside the @if?
If I do it inside the @if ofc it wont be detected outside the scope like normal programming and marked ans 'undefined'

Please help. false do the same and Null give me errors

Answer (score 0):

give $xtypeBtn some random default value as it will be reset anyway? If $xtypeYesOrNo can be undefined, give it a default value too?

```
@mixin btnNoBackgr30($divName, $iconName, $xtypeYesOrNo:default) {

  $xtypeBtn:default;

  @if $xtypeYesOrNo != default {
    // do whatever
  }

  @if xtypeYesOrNo == yes {
    $xtypeBtn: x-button-#{$divName};
  }

  @if xtypeYesOrNo == no {
    $xtypeBtn: #{$divName};
  }

  .#{$xtypeBtn} {
    properties: values;
  }

}
```

Comment: tried but the class becomes
`.default{propteries:values}` (!) 

I must be doing missing some small detail. it is as if it totally skips the @if argument

Comment: it still results in the class being set to whatever I set the $xtypeBtn to on the first row. In this case the class becomes `.default{properties:values;}`

It like totally skips the @if arguments. weird

Comment: gaaaah nevermind!!! hahaha I looked at my own question and did see I had missed out on the $ on the variables after the @if
Sorry for bothering!! *time to take a break and some air!*